# How to add handler to the format function of CString

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cstring

First I have a CString(MFC)

```
CString csSQL
```

When format a sql string, for example

```
csSQL.Format( szFormat, szTableName, szColumn, szValue, intValue )
```

I need to handle the special char in szValue, so I need write a new class MySQLString

```
mySQLcs.FormatSQL( szFormat, szTableName, szColumn, szValue, intValue )
```

which has the functionality

```
csSQL.Format( szFormat, szTableName, szColumn, HandleSpecialChar(szValue), intValue )
```

But because the parameter The format function accept is not fixed. I found it difficult. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* add a handler to the CString class.

You write a (new) function

```
CString FormatSQLString(CString const& format, CString const& tableName, CString const& columnName, CString const& value) {
  CString csSQL;
  return csSQL.Format(format, tableName, columnName, HandleSpecialChar(value));
}
```

*and* you wrap that function further up (e.g. `CString GetUpdateStmt(tableName, columnName, value)`) so that you don't have to sprinkle format strings all over your code.

When you write code where you use the input for an SQL statement in a structured way, be that as with a collection of functions such as I proposed, be that by using or creating a `SQLQueryStringBuilder` (made up name) class, then you won't have the problem of having to shoehorn something into the string formatting that doesn't belong there.

Comment: May be I am not clear, so I update the post, because the format function could accept different numbers of argument, so I donot want write many FormatSQLString with each function signature.

Comment: Again: Your string/formatting class is the wrong place to implement this. See edit of answer.